# deleting from table (join)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I've the table(t1) where column id is (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and another table(t2) where ID column is(1,2,3,4,5).

I want to DELETE entries from table t1 so that t1 ID column would become (1,2,3,4,5)

I've tried inner join and full outer join but none of them worked out.
I now this is a simple problem but I couldn't come over it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that you may be having some integrity issues in the database. Try to use constrains and foreing keys and you will save time cleaning orphan ids.

P.S. This does not make John answer less correct. I is just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DELETE from t1 where t1.ID not in (SELECT ID FROM t2)
```

So you didn't need to join in this case.

Comment: Sure, 10 minutes after

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2)
```

IN operator determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

Syntax:

```
test_expression [NOT] IN 
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]
    )
```

Read more about `IN` operator [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).